# Bloch dynamics on Bloch sphere

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Bloch equations of motion for a system are given by

```
  x'[t] == 1.3 x[t] z[t] ;
y'[t] == 1.3 z[t]*y[t] - 1.4 z[t];
z'[t] == 1.4 z'[t]^2 - 0.3 + 2 y[t] - 1 y[t];
```

With $x^2+y^2+z^2=1/4$. How can I generate the  Bloch dynamical evolution on a 3D plot (using fourth order Runge-Kutta method)? That is the curve given by the solution of above equation in a Bloch sphere?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to have `z'[t]^2` on the right hand side?

Comment: Have you tried `DSolve`? At least for short times, the trajectory will stay close to the sphere - provided that the ODE is really "living" on the sphere.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I think it makes it little complicated. I saw this example from a nice paper given here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.03406.pdf

Comment: So on which point in the paper am I supposed to stare? Equation (12) looks similar but there is only `z[t]^2` on the right hand side...

Comment: Nope, it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

So, the OP being reluctant to answer basic questions, I figured it out by myself. Equation (12) in cited paper is

```
eq = {
  x'[t] == 4 γ z[t] x[t] + 2 Ω z[t] Sin[ϕ],
  y'[t] ==  4 γ z[t] y[t] - 2 (1 - Ω Cos[ϕ]) z[t],
  z'[t] == -γ (1 - 4 z[t]^2) + 2 y[t] - 2 Ω (y[t] Cos[ϕ] + x[t] Sin[ϕ])
  }
```

Substituting

```
ϕ = 0;
γ = 3/10;
Ω = 1/2;
```

leads to a much simpler ODE than the OP posted. Now having a *meaningful* equation, we can solve it with `NDSolve`.

```
S = Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1/2];
p0 = RandomPoint[S];
T = 1000;
u = t \[Function] Evaluate[
    NDSolveValue[
     Join[eq, {x[0] == p0[[1]], y[0] == p0[[2]], z[0] == p0[[3]]}], {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, T},
     Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> "ImplicitRungeKutta"}
     ]
    ];
Show[
 Graphics3D[{Orange, Specularity[White, 30], S, White, Sphere[p0, 0.01]}],
 ParametricPlot3D[u[t], {t, 0, T}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]],
 Lighting -> "Neutral"
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Henrik. I tried to run your code, it shows "Part 2 of RandomPoint[Sphere[{0,0,0},1/2]] does not exist. ]", "Part 3 of RandomPoint[Sphere[{0,0,0},1/2]] does not exist", "Initial condition Sphere[{0.,0.,0.},0.5] is not a number or a \
rectangular array of numbers."

Comment: Appenrently, you have a Mathematica version before 10.2. Simply replace `RandomPoint[Sphere[{0,0,0},1/2]]` by `0.5 Normalize[RandomReal[{-1,1},3]]`.

Comment: This works really nice. But the plot looks different from the one given in the paper.